# win forms drop down auto compete User Search item if not found

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm doing drop Down Auto complete in winforms many of resource is online and i followed successfully complete.

if user search an item in dropdown it not match any of the list i have to give error to user "NO match found"

How can give error at the time of searching an item

```
cmbUserName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            cmbUserName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
     cmbUserName.DataSource = dt;
            cmbUserName.ValueMember = "htno";
            cmbUserName.DisplayMember = "sname";
```

i'm done at the time of other validation

Comment: Why do u want to show the error at the time of searching? Then u have use the TextChanged event which will pop errors untill a valid value is entered. I would suggest to throw the error when the combobox gets validated (when the focus is lost)

Comment: I'm don't have any idea to do that when use search string compare data table  is have item or not

Comment: Did my code help you?

Comment: Your code going wrong and not getting correct output  this is the working code   

string ss = cmbUserName.Text;

            Regex Expression = new Regex(ss, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var item = from a in dt.AsEnumerable() where a.Field<string>("sname").Contains(Regex.IsMatch(ss)) select a;

Comment: What is wrong about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. This will show the error when the ComboBox gets validated.

```
private void cmbUserName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!cmbUserName.Items.Contains(cmbUserName.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No match found");
            }
        }
```